# Can't test selenium in fitnesse

Tags: java, selenium, fitnesse

I'm learning how to use fitnesse . I trying to write a demo using fitnesse interact with selenium connect google's page but it not working.

```
My Java's code: 
{
package com.demo;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class HelloGooglePage {

    DefaultSelenium selenium;

    public HelloGooglePage(String host, int port, String browser, String baseURL) {
        this.selenium = new DefaultSelenium(host, port, browser, baseURL);
        System.out.println("hELLO");
        this.selenium.start();
    }

    public boolean open(String URL) {
        this.selenium.open(URL);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean type(String locator, String value) {
        boolean elementFound = this.selenium.isElementPresent(locator);
        if (elementFound) {
            this.selenium.click(locator);
        }
        return elementFound;
    }

    public boolean close() {
        this.selenium.close();
        return true;
    }

    public boolean stop() {
        this.selenium.stop();
        return true;
    }
```

my fitnesse's code:[Fitnesse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIHAC.jpg)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQeG9.jpg)

Comment: It will be more helpful if you paste your code into your question itself, and format them using code block, instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java Code:
{

```
private WebDriver driver;
private WebElement element;

private String URL;
private String elementName;
private String key;

public HelloGooglePage(String URL, String elementName, String key) {
    this.setURL(URL);
    this.setElementName(elementName);
    this.setKey(key);

    File file = new File("C:/Selenium/IEDriverServer.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
}

public void open(String URL) {
    driver.get(URL);
}

public void findElement(String elementName){
    element = driver.findElement(By.name(elementName));
}

public void sendKeys(String key){
    element.sendKeys(key);
}

@Test
public void submit(){
    element.submit();
    Assert.assertEquals("cheese - Google Search", driver.getTitle());
    driver.close();
}

public String getURL() {
    return URL;
}

public void setURL(String uRL) {
    URL = uRL;
}

public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}

public String getElementName() {
    return elementName;
}

public void setElementName(String elementName) {
    this.elementName = elementName;
}
```

Fitnesse Script:

!define COMMAND_PATTERN {"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\java" -cp %p %m}

!path path/fitlibrary-20080812.jar

!path path/fitnesse-20151230.jar

!path path/junit-4.10.jar

!path path/selenium-ie-driver-2.53.0.jar

!path path/selenium-java-2.53.0.jar

!path path/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar

!path target/classes

!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}

!|import |
|com.demo|

!define BrowserType1 {*iexplore}

!|script    |HelloGooglePage|http://www.google.com|q|cheese|

|open       |www.google.com                                |

|findElement|q                                             |

|sendKeys   |cheese                                        |

|submit                                                    |

Answer (score 0):

I think if you say simply

```
 |HelloGooglePage|
```

Nothing but it is scenario and you need to define it like below

```
|scenario|HelloGooglePage|
```

So that when ever used | HelloGooglePage| above scenario called and steps under that scenario will be executed. As per screenshot, directly used |HelloGooglePage| but not defined scenario any where.

for more explanation please look at [this](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.ScenarioTable)

And also [here](http://www.assertselenium.com/atdd/selenium-fitnesse/) is basic example

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: Thanks Murali . i found the answer on this "for more explanation please look at this" 's link you gave me. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you call `!|HelloGooglePage|`, it will try to find in your fixture for a constructor with no params, and it failed to get it, so Fitnesse translate the table into decision table and looks for scenario named "HelloGooglePage" instead. In that case, refer to his answer.

However, from your test code, it seems what you are trying to do is invoke the constructor in the fixture and execute command one by one, not a decision table style.

In that case, you can simply

1. remove line 14
2. add '!' in front of line 15

Comment: Thanks Xiawei Zhang . i tried but it not working. Got new error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium (i will investigate)

Comment: @hienvu use !path to add your dependency jar to the test as well